# Combining two time series with different ranges, when column headings are the dates

Tags: r, merge

I am stuck trying to combine two time series datasets that have different ranges and both are stored with item# in column1 and date as column headings. For example:

**df1**

```
#ITEM   1/1/16  1/2/16  1/3/16 ... 3/24/17    
#1      350     365     370    ... 400     
#2      100     95      101    ... 95   
#3      5       8       9      ... 15
```

The other dataset range is smaller, its in the same format, and both are daily frequency.

How can I append the rows of `df2` to `df1` despite having different ranges, but making sure the dates are aligned when merged? Happy with NA in the new dataframe where df#2 didn't have values for dates in `df1`

Should I create these at xts objects so that once they are merged I can easily pull data for item1 on X date? Or is there an easy way to do that with this format as well?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: Please provide sample data in a usable form. Paste into your question the output of `dput(df1[1:3, 1:5])` and `dput(df2[1:3, 1:5])`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `data.table::rbindlist(df1, df2)` with `fill = TRUE`
    that fills missing columns with NAs.

Example:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(item=c(1,2,3),"d1/1/16" = c(350,100,5) ,"d1/2/16" = c(360,120,7))
dt2 <- data.table(item=c(3,4,5),"d1/2/16" = c(50,50,2) ,"d1/3/16" = c(460,150,9))
l = list(dt1,dt2)
data.table::rbindlist(l, use.names= TRUE, fill=TRUE, idcol=TRUE )
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally in R time series are represented in columns, not rows.  Assuming we have `DF1` and `DF2` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end here are some alternatives

**1) zoo** we can create zoo series from each by transposing. Then merge them:

```
library(zoo)

fmt <- "%m/%d/%y"
z1 <- setNames(zoo(t(DF1[-1]), as.Date(names(DF1[-1]), fmt)), DF1[[1]])
z2 <- setNames(zoo(t(DF2[-1]), as.Date(names(DF2[-1]), ftm)), DF2[[1]])

z <- merge(z1, z2)
```

It is probably best to leave this as the zoo series `z` but if you want to transform to a data frame then use: `fortity.zoo(z)`

**2) base** Alternately, without zoo using `fmt` from above:

```
d1 <- data.frame(as.Date(names(DF1[-1]), fmt), t(DF1[-1]))
names(d1) <- c("Index", DF1[[1]])

d2 <- data.frame(as.Date(names(DF2[-1]), fmt), t(DF2[-1]))
names(d2) <- c("Index", DF2[[1]])

merge(d1, d2, by = "Index", all = TRUE)
```

**Note:** The input in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "ITEM   1/1/16  1/2/16  1/3/16  3/24/17    
1      350     365     370     400     
2      100     95      101     95   
3      5       8       9      15"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
DF1 <- DF[1:2, 1:3]
DF2 <- DF[3, -3]
```